# How to change color of text in javascript in Typing test

Tags: javascript

```
    function speedCal(){
        function Speed(){
        var inputText=document.getElementById("inputbox").value;
        inputText = inputText.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
        inputText=inputText.trim();
        var arr=inputText.split(" ");
        var text=document.getElementById('textbox').value;
        text=text.split(" ");   
        var Err=0;
        if (arr[0]==='') {
            document.getElementById('speed').innerHTML="0 WPM | 0 WPM";
        document.getElementById('errors').innerHTML="0 Words";
        document.getElementById('accuracy').innerHTML="0%";
        }
        else{
        for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
                                        if(text[i]!=arr[i]){
                                            Err+=1;
                                            //text[i].style.color="red";
                                        }

                                     }
        var Acc=Math.floor((arr.length-Err)/arr.length*100);

        document.getElementById('speed').innerHTML=""+arr.length+" WPM | "+(arr.length-Err)+" WPM";
        document.getElementById('errors').innerHTML=""+Err+" Words";
        document.getElementById('accuracy').innerHTML=""+Acc+"%";
        }
        }
        setTimeout(Speed, 31000);
}
```

I am trying to create a typing test. When typed text doesn't matches given word, the color of the word shud change to red. I tried in code text[i]!=arr[i], but it didn't work. I tried to add a javascript which i later commented because it didn't work, please help how to do it. Please check code and suggest me ways to do it.